# $\int\frac{1}{x^3-1}dx$. Approach using complex numbers?

Tags: integration, complex-integration

$\displaystyle\int\frac{1}{x^3-1}dx$. I've had this in mind for days... I first write the integrand in partial fractions:$$\frac{1}{x^3-1}=\frac{A}{x-1}+\frac{B}{x-\omega}+\frac{C}{x-\omega^2}=\frac{(A+B+C)x^2+(A+B\omega+c\omega^2)x+(A+B\omega^2+C\omega)}{(x-1)(x-\omega)(x-\omega^2)}$$where $\omega$ is a primitive $3$rd root of unity. By comparing coefficients and then applying Gaussian elimination, I have $\{A=\frac{1}{3},B=\frac{\omega}{3},C=\frac{\omega^2}{3}$. Thus$$\displaystyle\int\frac{1}{x^3-1}dx=\frac{1}{3}\operatorname{log}(x-1)+\frac{\omega}{3}\operatorname{log}(x-\omega)+\frac{\omega^2}{3}\operatorname{log}(x-\omega^2)+C$$At first glance, I thought this method is brilliant. It is easy to be understood and generalised, but then I thought: Will I run into some problems? Because I know that complex logarithm has an apparent branch cut. Logarithm is not a well-defined function on $\Bbb C$ unless we specify the use of principal argument in its evaluation. Can somebody tell if this approach is appropriate or not?

**P.S.** Apparently I'm not familiar with topics in complex analysis, and I won't be able to learn such advanced things until after two or three years in university. :(

Comment: As far as I know, this approach is correct and usually yields the right answers. The same approach is used to derive formulas for $\int 1/(x^2-1) dx$ etc.

Comment: The use of partial fraction for $\int\frac{1}{x^2-1}dx$ does not involve complex integration though.

Comment: He meant $\int \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^2 + 1}$, which can be done via complex integration to get a logarithmic closed form.